# Is there a way to get a video frame from CipherInputStream?

Tags: android, video, encryption, mediametadataretriever

In my android app, I have a video file which was encrypted by `Cipher`, now I want to retrieve a video frame as thumbnail.

`MediaMetadataRetriever` could do this job in normally, the method [void setDataSource (MediaDataSource dataSource)](https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource(android.media.MediaDataSource)) maybe the key to my problem, but it is added in API level 23, I need to do the job on lower API level too.

I found a library called [`FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever), but it can't set data source by custom inputstream.

So does someone have a good idea?

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted?

Comment: I gather you want to avoid creating a decrypted file anywhere except in memory. You should at least see if you can create a solution that does what you want in API level 23 and above. I don't have an answer for your general problem, but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45439170/238704) answer can help.