# scriptella executor with xml as string instead of file

Tags: java, etl, scriptella

I am trying to use scriptella in my project to copy data from one db to another, now the application has a frontend which users can use to create mapping between tables and create dynamic queries, now currently once the user submits the frontend queries are passed via a query engine and a scriptella xml is created using freemarker template

however to execute the xml the executor expects a file instead of a xml string currently i am achieving this by creating a xml in temp directory and deleting it post execution of query, is there any way i can skip file creation and execute the query as a xml string

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [URLStreamHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) that will serve streams directly from memory. This is similar to what was done in [AbstractTestCase](https://github.com/scriptella/scriptella-etl/blob/master/core/src/test/scriptella/AbstractTestCase.java). It can be registered by calling [URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#setURLStreamHandlerFactory(java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory)). See [Registering and using a custom java.net.URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409796/1129542) or [Is it possible to create an URL pointing to an in-memory object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384783/is-it-possible-to-create-an-url-pointing-to-an-in-memory-object)

After that, use 
[EtlExecutor.newExecutor(java.net.URL)](http://scriptella.org/docs/api/scriptella/execution/EtlExecutor.html#newExecutor(java.net.URL)) with the new URI, e.g. new `URL("memory://file")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case.  I downloaded the code and made a small change in the core.  Due to some private functions I had no choice.
in
package scriptella.configuration.ConfigurationFactory
I added the following function:

```
public ConfigurationEl createConfigurationFromTxt(String xml, final ParametersCallback externalParameters ) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = DBF.newDocumentBuilder();
            db.setEntityResolver(ETL_ENTITY_RESOLVER);
            db.setErrorHandler(ETL_ERROR_HANDLER);

            final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
            final Document document = db.parse(in);
            HierarchicalParametersCallback params = new HierarchicalParametersCallback(
                    externalParameters == null ? NullParametersCallback.INSTANCE : externalParameters, null);
            PropertiesSubstitutor ps = new PropertiesSubstitutor(params);

            return new ConfigurationEl(new XmlElement(
                    document.getDocumentElement(), resourceURL, ps), params);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Unable to load document: " + e, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException("Unable to parse document: " + e, e);
        }
    }
```

Then from my code I can do something like this:

```
ConfigurationFactory cf = new ConfigurationFactory();
ConfigurationEl conf = cf.createConfigurationFromTxt(FETCH_ETLS, p);
EtlExecutor exec = new EtlExecutor(conf);
```