# How to load Hibernate XML configuration without storing to file?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm building a system that gets Hibernate XML configuration files over the network both (cfg.xml and hbm.xml) and dynamically reconfigured Hibernate session.

But, it seems like `StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure` and `MetadataSources.addFile` only supports `URL`, `File` or `resourceName`, meaning it seems like the XML files have to pre-saved and can't be handed as a String or in memory.

Is there a way to avoid this saving to file?

Comment: Well, you could build up [URL handling for in-memory data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384783/is-it-possible-to-create-an-url-pointing-to-an-in-memory-object).

Comment: Thanks I just found this answer :) but I hopped to find something more straight forward.